# Saving boolean in md-radio-button?

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angular-material

I want to save `true` on **Yes** answer and `false` on **No**:

```
            <div layout-gt-sm="row">
                Insured?

                <md-radio-group ng-model="vehicle.insured">

                    <md-radio-button value="true" class="md-primary">Yes</md-radio-button>
                    <md-radio-button value="false"> No </md-radio-button>

                </md-radio-group>

            </div>
```

it saves the value in the database, but it doesn't bind the existing value, so there is no selected answer when the user retrieve a record

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Guess you mean to initialize the md-radio-group, try replace `value` to `ng-value`.

```js
var app = angular.module('angularMaterialApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.vehicle = {
      Insured: true
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularMaterialApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

  <p>Selected Value: <span class="radioValue">{{ vehicle.Insured }}</span>
  </p>
  <md-radio-group ng-model="vehicle.Insured">
    <md-radio-button ng-value="true">Yes</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button ng-value="false">No</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
  <hr />

</body>

</html>
```